# Asp.NET MVC ajax is loading bad page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a layout page inside which i have a table with delete button

[image: first page before click of delete button]

when i press a delete button it is showing some thing like .

[image]

my ajex option is like.

```
@{
    AjaxOptions xPost = new AjaxOptions();
    xPost.HttpMethod = "POST";
    xPost.Confirm = "Do you wish to submit this form ?";
    xPost.OnBegin = "OnBegin";
    xPost.OnComplete = "OnComplete";
    xPost.OnFailure = "OnFailure";
    xPost.OnSuccess = "OnSuccess";
    xPost.LoadingElementDuration = 1000;
    xPost.LoadingElementId = "divProgress";
    xPost.UpdateTargetId = "divResponse";
    xPost.InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace;

}
```

and on delete i am subbmiting the form to a controll like

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        ContactPersonManager.Delete(id);
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ajax, you could return the URL from your action and have it redirected in javascript:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    ContactPersonManager.Delete(id);
    return Json(new { success = true, redirecturl = Url.Action("List") });
}
```

Then add something like this to your OnSuccess handler in javascript:

**Javascript**

```
function anOnSuccessFunction (data)
{
  if (data.success == true)
  {
     window.location = data.redirecturl;
  }
}
```

**Markup**

Make sure you point your Ajax options to the javascript function.

```
xPost.OnSuccess = "anOnSuccessFunction";
```